# How to use webcam on laptop windows 7 to simulator phone camera in WP7 emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, webcam

Anybody knows about that??? Please show me how to do it!
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Featuresandlimitationsoftheemulator) that the camera, compass, and gyroscope are not supported in the emulator. You need a real device to test those features.

Comment: I don't think so :)
We can do it with Emlator, here:
http://blog.darkthread.net/blogs/darkthreadtw/archive/2010/08/18/camera-for-wp7-emulator.aspx

Thanks for your commnent, vcsjones! :)

Comment: @KhắcPhục That's not really getting the camera to work with the emulator, it's writing a full blown visual source that emulates it (not to mention it requires a server) - but hey, if it works for you.